# Why doesn't dropFirst return an array, but dropLast does?

Tags: swift

This function builds successfully

```
func dropLastFromArray(_ array: [Any]) -> [Any] {
    return array.dropLast()
}
```

but this function does not

```
func dropFirstFromArray(_ array: [Any]) -> [Any] {
    return array.dropFirst()
}
```

it gives a build error: `No 'dropFirst' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '[Any]'`

What is going on? In the docs, they both show a return type of `ArraySlice<Element>`. It seems to me that one of these two must be wrong.

I'm using XCode 12.5.1 if that matters

Comment: Why do you work with arrays of Any? That is almost always wrong.

Comment: @matt I don't; I was just creating a minimal example

Comment: Yes, understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both your declarations are wrong; both `dropFirst` and `dropLast` return an ArraySlice, not an Array.

The reason that the `dropLast` example doesn't complain in the same way as the `dropFirst` example is that there is *another* `dropLast`, namely *Sequence* `dropLast`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3128805-droplast

Failing to find an Array `dropLast` that works for your code, the compiler falls back on the Sequence `dropLast`, because an Array is also a Sequence.

The difference you are experiencing is in fact thus reflecting the way Sequence `dropFirst` and `dropLast` differ from one another. The former returns a DropFirstSequence, whereas the latter returns an Array. And you can see why. Dropping the last element is trivial: we just shorten the sequence count by one. But to drop the first element would be a big deal if we had to throw away the first element and renumber all the elements, so we don't; we use a special type that keeps the original sequence and just *ignores* the first element.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make my code work with ArraySlices instead of arrays. It was a small thing, so it wasn't hard to make work